# Positioning Conky and deleting the black background of Conky

Tags: conky

I really like the look Conky *should* give to my desktop, but it seems to fail to work properly. Conky's window is not transparent, but black. It also is positioned in the top_left position. I want it to be in the middle_middle of my screen.

```
# Conky settings #
background yes
update_interval 1
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes

# Window specifications #
gap_x 0
gap_y 0
minimum_size 600 0
maximum_width 711
own_window yes
own_window_type dock
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
#own_window_argb_visual yes
#own_window_argb_value 0
#border_margin 0
#border_inner_margin 0
#border_outer_margin 0
#alignment middle_middle

# Graphics settings #
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no

# Text settings #
use_xft yes
xftalpha 0
xftfont Open Sans Light:size=10

override_utf8_locale yes

imlib_cache_size 0

# Color scheme #
default_color FFFFFF

color1 FFFFFF
color2 FFFFFF
color3 FFFFFF
color4 FFFFFF
color5 FFFFFF
color6 FFFFFF
color7 333333

TEXT
${execi 300 curl -s "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=733881&u=c" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}


${font Raleway:weight=Light :size=100}${voffset -40}${alignc}${time %H}${alignc}:${alignc}${time %M}
${font Raleway:weight=Light:size=32}${voffset -40}${alignc}${time %A %B %d}


${font Raleway:size=20}
${voffset -64}${alignc 216}${execi 300 grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "temp=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}°
${font Raleway:weight=Light:size=14}
${voffset -52}${alignc 122}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°
${voffset -19}${alignc 12}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°
${voffset -19}${alignc -98}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==4'}°
${voffset -19}${alignc -208}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "high=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==5'}°


${font Raleway:weight=Light:size=10}
${voffset -10}${alignc 98}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2'}°
${voffset -14}${alignc -12}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3'}°
${voffset -14}${alignc -122}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==4'}°
${voffset -14}${alignc -232}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "low=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==5'}°


${font Raleway:weight=Light:size=14}
${voffset -26}${alignc 220}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==1' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}
${voffset -18}${alignc 110}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}
${voffset -19}${alignc}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}
${voffset -18}${alignc -110}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==4' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}
${voffset -19}${alignc -220}${execi 300 grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "day=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==5' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'}


${font Raleway:weight=Light:size=14}
${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather-icons/$(grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*").png ~/.cache/weather-1.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-1.png -p 61,320 -s 32x32}${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather-icons/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==2').png ~/.cache/weather-2.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-2.png -p 171,320 -s 32x32}${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather-icons/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==3').png ~/.cache/weather-3.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-3.png -p 281,320 -s 32x32}${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather-icons/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==4').png ~/.cache/weather-4.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-4.png -p 391,320 -s 32x32}${execi 300 cp -f ~/.conky-weather-icons/$(grep "yweather:forecast" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*" | awk 'NR==5').png ~/.cache/weather-5.png}${image ~/.cache/weather-5.png -p 501,320 -s 32x32}${font}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem:      Conky's window is not transparent, but black.
Solution:     own_window_argb_value 0 # Set conky background opacity (0 transparent, 63-127-191 25-50-75% translucent, 255 opaque)
Prerequisite: own_window_argb_visual yes # Enable ARGB settings

---

Problem:      It also is positioned in the top_left position. I want it to be in the middle_middle of my screen.
Solution:       alignment middle_middle # Display in middle of screen, horizontally and vertically centered

---

That should fix your issues.  Have fun Conkying!

Comment: Conky is great, but the documentation is a little daunting for beginners...

Answer (score 0):

You can try Conky Color wich is really easy to set up.

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/CONKY-colors?content=92328

Comment: Isn't that a Conky theme? Or is it an application to set Conky up with?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `own_window_type` to `dock`, set it to `override`. This will allow you to set the alignment to `middle_middle`, or anywhere else for that matter. Also, your config has `alignment middle_middle` commented out, which you'll need to uncomment. Also, remove (or keep commented) the `own_window_argb_visual` and `own_window_argb_value` lines as these are making your background black.

Comment: This didn't move it to the center of my desktop, nor did it make the black background go away. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: Is your `alignment middle_middle` line still commented out in your config (does the line start with a #)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole thing working transparent and top right so you can see the exact correct lines in position (with a few extras that you might like - the ESSID, Link & Bitrate are only for Linux - miss those lines in Windows. Also substitute the name of your wireless adapter where I have put mine - wlp13s0):

```
conky.config = {
    alignment = 'top_right',
    background = false,
    border_width = 1,
    cpu_avg_samples = 2,
    default_color = 'white',
    default_outline_color = 'white',
    default_shade_color = 'white',
    double_buffer = true,
    draw_borders = false,
    draw_graph_borders = true,
    draw_outline = false,
    draw_shades = false,
    extra_newline = false,
    font = 'DejaVu Sans Mono:size=10',
    gap_x = 60,
    gap_y = 60,
    minimum_height = 5,
    minimum_width = 5,
    net_avg_samples = 2,
    no_buffers = true,
    out_to_console = false,
    out_to_ncurses = false,
    out_to_stderr = false,
    out_to_x = true,
    own_window = true,
    own_window_class = 'Conky',
    own_window_type = 'desktop',
    show_graph_range = false,
    show_graph_scale = false,
    stippled_borders = 0,
    update_interval = 1.0,
    uppercase = false,
    use_spacer = 'none',
    use_xft = true,
    own_window_argb_visual = true,
    own_window_argb_value = 50,
    double_buffer = true,
    update_interval = 2.0,
}

conky.text = [[
${color grey}Info:$color ${scroll 32 Conky $conky_version}
${color grey}System:$color $sysname
${color}$nodename
${color grey}Kernel:$color $kernel
${color grey}Machine:$color $machine
$hr
${color grey}Uptime:$color $uptime
${color grey}Frequency (in MHz):$color $freq
${color grey}Frequency (in GHz):$color $freq_g
${color grey}RAM Usage:$color $mem/$memmax - $memperc% ${membar 4}
${color grey}Swap Usage:$color $swap/$swapmax - $swapperc% ${swapbar 4}
${color grey}CPU Usage:$color $cpu% ${cpubar 4}
${color grey}CPU temperature:$color ${hwmon 4 temp 1}°C
${color grey}Processes:$color $processes  ${color grey}Running:$color $running_processes
$hr
${color grey}File systems:
 / $color${fs_used /}/${fs_size /} ${fs_bar 6 /}
${color grey}Wireless networking:
Up:$color ${upspeed wlp13s0} ${color grey} - Down:$color ${downspeed wlp13s0}
${color grey}ESSID:${color} ${wireless_essid wlp13s0}
${color grey}Bitrate:${color} ${wireless_bitrate wlp13s0}
${color grey}Link quality:${color} ${wireless_link_qual_perc wlp13s0}%
$hr
${color grey}Name              PID     CPU%   MEM%
${color lightgrey} ${top name 1} ${top pid 1} ${top cpu 1} ${top mem 1}
${color lightgrey} ${top name 2} ${top pid 2} ${top cpu 2} ${top mem 2}
${color lightgrey} ${top name 3} ${top pid 3} ${top cpu 3} ${top mem 3}
${color lightgrey} ${top name 4} ${top pid 4} ${top cpu 4} ${top mem 4}
${color lightgrey} ${top name 5} ${top pid 5} ${top cpu 5} ${top mem 5}
${color lightgrey} ${top name 6} ${top pid 6} ${top cpu 6} ${top mem 6}
]]
```